# How can I use regex in C++ to extract text including spaces between parenthesis

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to extract the following into 3 strings (text1, all of timestamp including whitespace and excluding parenthesis, text3). The following is the example text and my code.

`text1(Mon Jan 10 10:10:10 2000):text2`

and I have the following code to extract this

```
regex pattern(".+\\(.+\\):.+");
if( regex_match(message, pattern) ){
      auto regex_iterator = std::sregex_iterator(message.begin(), message.end(), pattern);
      ...
```

Comment: Which exactly are the three strings you wish to have extracted?

Comment: check my updated post

Comment: You want regex_search instead of regex_match.  Look at the example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at

Comment: You probably want something like https://onlinegdb.com/_zDU63p0q

Comment: You can split the string on matches of the regular expression `\(|\):`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j88Shk/1).

Comment: This search is utterly trivial if you don’t use a regular expression. Don’t make things harder than they have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::regex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  std::string message = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "";
  std::smatch match;
  if (regex_match( message, match, std::regex("(.*?)\\((.*?)\\):(.*)") ))
  {
    for (auto m : match)
      std::cout << m.str() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Using `std::string` methods:

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  std::string message = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "";
  auto n1 = message.find( "(" );
  auto n2 = message.find( "):" );
  if ((n1 != message.npos) and (n2 != message.npos))
  {
    std::cout
      << message                         << "\n"
      << message.substr( 0,    n1      ) << "\n"
      << message.substr( n1+1, n2-n1-1 ) << "\n"  // n1+1 for length of "("
      << message.substr( n2+2          ) << "\n"; // n2+2 for length of "):"
  }
}
```

Compile either example with something like:

```
cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std:c++17 a.cpp
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
```

The way to quote a single argument (with spaces) for playing with it differs between Windows and Linux:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | `a.exe "text1(Mon Jan 10 10:10:10 2000):text2"` |
| Linux | `./a.out 'text1(Mon Jan 10 10:10:10 2000):text2'` |